# Add space from extended file system to ext4

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I have an 128GB SSD that's shared with windows, and I have allocated 80 GB to windows and the rest to Linux. Now I have run out of space on my home directory (`/dev/sdb7`) and want to add to it from `/dev/sdb1`, but I can't figure out how to do that. I am booted on a usb so I should be able to make the appropriate changes.

How can I move space from the extended file system `sdb1` to `sdb7`?

[image]

Comment: Is your linux installation using lvm? Or just trying using gparted?

Comment: @rafaelphp im just using gparted

Comment: When you move the 'left' edge of the root partition, you will have to reinstall grub. It is possible, but an extra step to take. - And please explain how you use `/dev/sdb7` and `/dev/sdb2`, which is the root partition `/` and what is the other one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First, boot into Windows and use [Windows tools](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309169.aspx) to shrink the big windows partition `/dev/sdb6`**. This is because Windows often does not like it when its partition size is changed without its knowledge.

It looks like you still have 10 GB of Space in `/dev/sdb7`, but almost no space in `/dev/sdb2`.

**Boot from a Live USB/DVD of Ubuntu and use the Try Ubuntu without installing,** and then open gparted to move or shrink the other partitions.

1. Make sure all the partitions are unmounted. With the live USB/DVD the internal drives should be unmounted by default, unless you clicked on the drive icons in the launcher to mount them.
2. Move `/dev/dsb7` to the left and optionally increase the size if you want. Make sure you have some free unallocated space to the right of `/dev/sdb7` inside `/dev/sdb1`.
3. Shrink `/dev/sdb1` so that all the unallocated space inside `/dev/sdb1` is now unallocated space in between `/dev/sdb1` and `/dev/sdb2`.
4. Resize `/dev/sdb2` to fill the unallocated space.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following steps:

Shrink /dev/sdb6

Move /dev/sdb7 to the left

Shrink /dev/sdb1

Move /dev/sdb2 to the left

Grow /dev/sdb2